# What does "tc" in tcgetsid mean?

Tags: c, linux

I don't see the manpage explains what "tc" means in "tcgetsid". Could anybody explain what it stands for?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcgetsid.3.html

Comment: Terminal Control?? [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetsid.html) *get the process group ID for the session leader for the controlling terminal*

Comment: All the `tcXXX` functions are for terminal control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't say it in the man pages, but all the `tcXXX` functions are used for controlling different features of terminals, so "tc" presumably stands for "terminal control".

```
/usr/share/man/man3/tcdrain.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcflow.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcflush.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcgetattr.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcgetpgrp.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcgetsid.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcsendbreak.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcsetattr.3
/usr/share/man/man3/tcsetpgrp.3
```